# Where is the "Include your .blend" button?

Tags: feature-request

I have to say the [GiantCowFilms](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms) [services](http://giantcowfilms.com/) are really amazing. It seems they are "official BSE .blend cloud", at least from my point of view (orthographic?). The ability to post a .blend file, link it to a question, etc, is amazing. (Did you try his [.HDRs](http://giantcowfilms.com/category/hdrs/) ?)
But how can a newcomer know that?
Asking a question allows many things but no link to this service.
[image: Ask question shot]

It seems we need a "post your blend" button. The blender icon should help newbies to find the good tool.
[image: auto answer]

Why not?
How to make newbies life easier? (and ours too!)
Do you have an idea ? (about that... :) )

Comment: Well, [we do have a user script](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/634/3127) to add such a button; however, only users familiar with blend-exchange install the user script, so it doesn't help much in this case. We are also [running a community promotion ad](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1016/3127) that appears on the sidebar, which helps a little bit. Overall though, full integration would be nice. Even better, though, would be a stack-exchange guaranteed and funded (or even maintained) service.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms 100% agreed. Very cool for everyone but newbs...

Comment: Exactly the issue :/

Comment: @GiantCowFilms not about you hosting this, the future of this service if you leave us (please don't!!) but some questions could be asked.

Comment: As far as the future, the code is open source, and as long as I give warning, someone else could take over the service. I'd only have to setup a redirect for the domain (which I don't intend to party with anytime soon). If I got run over by a bus (died suddenly), something might go wrong though. But I don't intend for that to happen any time soon either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to officially endorse a proper built in integration (so any staff wondering across this post know that blend-exchange is ready).

Firstly, we already have an embed page ([http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/eembedUpload/?qurl=[url of question]](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedUpload/?qurl=))

which is ready for use for use in a popup window (I can easily add iframe support as well if need be). Also, [the code is open source](https://github.com/GiantCowFilms/Blend-Exchange/tree/master/Blend-exchangePHP) if any stack exchange developers would rather just make their own changes.

All that being said, I think we'd all prefer if SE acquired a proper file hosting service, this one has limited funds and limited space :/.

Comment: I wonder if "I" can accept this answer.

Comment: Sure, but wouldn't help much. SE is the one we need to be endorsing ideas. :/

Comment: wait and see...