# Suggesting adding a button/link for uploading .blend file above the text box

Tags: feature-request

How/where do I upload my .blend file comes up all the time. I suggest adding a button/link to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for uploading a .blend file above the text box with the other options like **B**, Italic, Hyperlink, etc...

Comment: There are probably technical limitations at play here, not sure the editor toolbar is modifiable on a per-site basis, but I 'd vote for this yes. Along with a button to insert the `<kbd>` formatting tags

Comment: Note that blend exchange is not part of this site, but was created and is run very generously by a user : @giantcowfilms.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos [We have a user script for a `<kbd>` button](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/388/599), in case you weren't already aware of it.

Comment: There's also a [user script which adds a blend-exchange button](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/634/3127).

Comment: I use [Vivaldi Browser](https://vivaldi.com) which has a nice *Insert Note* feature, one of which is this keyboard markup, which I use to insert that snippet, but a userscripts sound pretty neat too. Definitely gonna check those out.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a great idea, but we'll need to get SE to add this. We don't have control over much of the help center content.

I propose adding something like this at the end of the ["how to ask" page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

> - **Help us help you**
>     If your question involves troubleshooting strange behavior,
>     the fastest and simplest way of finding the answer is often by [providing a blendfile](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/297/599) and/or screenshots for others to examine.

And something like this to the [ask question page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ([à la codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)):

> How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about blender behaving differently than expected?**
>
> Chances are, the fastest way to find an answer is by [providing a blendfile](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/297/599) for others to examine. If your file is especially large or you don't wish to share its contents, try to pare it down by deleting extraneous objects and/or replacing the actual meshes with placeholders.

---

Please feel free to edit these and improve wording etc, or propose your own in another answer.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed the question was mainly about the buttons directly above the textbox, not the help on the side.. I don't think there's much chance of getting anything official in the textbox buttons ([we've](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/297/599) tried [before](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1085/599), but [we haven't even got an official `<kbd>` button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102841/238438)). However we might be able to get text added to the help/ask question sidebar, which IMO would be the next best thing.

Comment: That would be the next best thing. A lot of new users simply arn't aware of http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and that sharing their .blend is helpful in a lot of ways.

Comment: Doesn't the wording of that first (and possibly the second) help message go against the general idea that [not all questions need a blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/should-all-ask-a-question-pages-encourage-the-poster-to-upload-their-blend) and that ideally we would rather answer a well-worded, illustrated question *without* downloading a file, save for the cases where they really are required? I feel the question was more about letting the user know where the best place to upload a file was, not indicating that uploading is always the best option.

Comment: e.g. "If you need to add a blend file to your question use blend-exchange...etc."

Comment: @RayMairlot Edited to add emphasis to the "if your question involves troubleshooting"

Comment: So now we will don't need to remind users to: *"Please upload file to blend-exchange..."* but *"Please read How To Ask page to see how to upload file to blend-exchange"*. It's better then nothing but I can't see this as a solution. Too often users whom upload file to random hostings also show in different ways that they didn't see any help page before asking question. Or Search box. Or Google. Maybe just something short and clear in sidebar on ask question page as *"If you need to upload blend file use blend-exchange..."* and there give instructions how to prepare file.

Comment: I simply cannot understand how adding for example a simple link with text could be such problem :/